# How to display HTML5 Geolocation API on page load/without clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html

Below I have the code to use HTML5 Geolocation API. In every example I've read on it, it always involves clicking a button to display location. However, I'd like to show it right as the user loads the page. I thought I had it in my code below, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id = "storeLocation"></div>
```

// div in html

```
var showLocation = document.getElementById("storeWeather");

function userLocation () {
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPoints);
  } else {
    showLocation.innerHTML = "Your browser does not support this feature.";
  }
}

function showPoints (position) {
  showLocation.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br> Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace by this :

```
var showLocation = document.getElementById("storeLocation");
...
//end or you js code
document.body.onload = function(){
    userLocation ();
};
```